# Adding ImageView to listView item via ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, imageview, android-arrayadapter

I wanted to add several image views programmatically that depend on if there're image to view or not .. so I tried this inside my ArrayAdapter class .. what I'm doing here is to check is there any urls for extra images or not and then creating a number of imageview to show these images on it

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HeaderHolder headerRow = null;
    View hs = null;
    if (position == 0) {
        if (hs == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
            LinearLayout linear =(LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.headerlayout);

            TextView main = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.headLine);
            main.setText(appManager.getDetails().getTitle());
            // Log.d("display width ", "" + display.getWidth());

            // TextViewJustify.justifyText(main, display.getWidth() - 400f
            // );
            TextView pubDate = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.pubdate);
            pubDate.setText(appManager.getDetails().getPubDate());
            TextView detailsBody = (TextView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.detailsBody);

            detailsBody.setText(appManager.getDetails().getBody());
            // TextViewJustify.justifyText(detailsBody, display.getWidth() -
            // 400f );
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.main);
            String url = appManager.getDetails().getMainImageLink();
            if (url != null) {

                loader.fetchDrawableOnThread(appManager.getDetails()
                        .getMainImageLink(), iv);

            }

            if (appManager.getDetails().images.size() > 0) {


                for (int i = 0; i < appManager.getDetails().images.size(); i++) {
                    im[i]= new ImageView(context);
                    im[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    im[i].setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    linear.addView(im[i]);
                    loader.fetchDrawableOnThread(appManager.getDetails().images.get(i), im[i]);
                }
            }



            ImageView play = (ImageView) rowView
                    .findViewById(R.id.videoYoutube);
            if (appManager.getDetails().getVideos().size() > 0) {
                play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(appManager
                                        .getDetails().getVideos().get(0))));
                    }
                });
            }

            headerRow = new HeaderHolder();
            headerRow.headLine = main;
            headerRow.pubDate = pubDate;
            headerRow.main = iv;
            headerRow.lin = linear;
            headerRow.details_images = im ;
            headerRow.playButton = play;
            hs = rowView;
            hs.setTag(headerRow);
        }


    }

    else if (position >= 1) {

        ..............

    }

    return rowView;
}
```

it always gives me error at `im[i]= new ImageView(context);` i don't know why !

my error log

```
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806): java.lang.NullPointerException
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at        com.nazzelha.youm7.DetailsAdapter.getView(DetailsAdapter.java:111)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   06-26 12:21:49.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2806):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what kind of error it gives you? Have you specified the length of your im array?

Comment: Check your logcat and tell us the error u r getting. And error may be beacuse , u r not putting context value to context variable. 
Intialize context as class variable.
In constructor put this.context = context; Whatever its first parameter is

Comment: I get the context from the  constructor of the adapter so there's no problem with that

Comment: @vezikon use List instead of array of im (ImageView) objects

Comment: @MocialovBoris I will try and tell you

Answer (score 0):

This means that you probably forgot to initialize your **im** (ImageView) array, which should be done by:

```
ImageView [ ] im = new ImageView [ 3 ];
im[0] = new ImageView(context);  //filling one element at a time
temps[1] = ..;
temps[2] = ..;
```

or use **for** loop:

```
for(int imgNr = 0; imgNr < 3; imgNr++)
{
      //fill one element at a time
      im[imgNr] = new ImageView(context);    
}
```

or use any other known method for initialization and filling up an array of objects.

You have to do this because array's size is always fixed in Java. Typically instead of using an array, you'd use an implementation of List or any other alternative, which does not need the size definition.

If array is needed afterwards in application, **toArray** method may be used to retrieve array of objects residing in List